# How does app like spotify to keep music on whe system goes block and sleep

Tags: java, android

I need to keep music playing when the screen is block and the system goes to sleep. As app like spotify does, the music keep playing. What I did without success is:

```
    public void doPower() {
       if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            String packageName = getActivity().getPackageName();
            PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) 
    getActivity().getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
            if (!pm.isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations(packageName)) {
                try {
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
              intent.setAction(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS);
                    intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + packageName));
                   startActivity(intent);

                } catch (Exception e) {
        getActivity().getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I can not ignore batery optimizations any more in new android versions.

Comment: There are lots of open source music players online. You can check them out and see how they implement theirs. Here is [an example](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/com.simplemobiletools.musicplayer/)

Comment: Define a mediaplayer object in a service class

Comment: I defined a mediaplayer service class but it keeps going off whe system goes to sleep